# How do I retain global access to my pointers to objects created on the Heap

Tags: c++

I'm working on a text adventure game in order to practice C++.  What I have is something like this so far:
In main():

```
#include <iostream>
#include "game_functions1.h"
#include "game_functions2.h"
#include "RoomsInit.h"
#include "exitsInit.h"
#include "playerInit.h"

using namespace std;



int main()
{

    GameDescription();

    while(PlayGame) {}


   return 0;
}
```

I've included my Room Initialization cpp file, Exit Init file and Player Init files. They look like this:

```
       RoomInit.h:

#ifndef ROOMSINIT_H_INCLUDED
#define ROOMSINIT_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;







#endif // ROOMSINIT_H_INCLUDED
```

and its corresponding cpp file:

```
#include "RoomsInit.h"
#include "Room.h"




    string roomName1 = "On a deserted beach";
    string roomDescr1 = "You are standing on a deserted beach. To the east, a "
                       "crystal blue ocean\n dances in the morning sun. To the "
                       "west is a dense jungle, and somewhere\n far off, you can "
                       "hear the singing of a strange bird. The white, sandy \n"
                       "beach runs out of sight to the north and south.\n\n\n";

    Room* p_deserted_beach = new Room(roomName1, roomDescr1);



    string roomName2 = "In the ocean";
    string roomDescr2 = "You are swimming in the ocean. The sunlight dances\n"
                       "merrily on the waves.\n\n\n";

    Room* p_in_the_ocean = new Room(roomName2, roomDescr2);



    string roomName3 = "Caught in a current";
    string roomDescr3 = "You are caught in a current that is pulling you\n"
                       "toward the north. I'm not sure, but...I think this \n"
                       "may not have been such a good idea. Just sayin'.\n\n\n";

    Room* p_caught_in_a_Current = new Room(roomName3, roomDescr3);



    string roomName4 = "Caught in a strong current";
    string roomDescr4 = "The current is much stronger here. Okay, now I'm\n"
                       "sure. This was a really bad idea. Er...how long can \n"
                       "you tread water...'cause...with a little luck, we should\n"
                       "hit the East coast of Japan in about 3 weeks.\n\n\n";

    Room* p_caught_in_a_strong_current = new Room(roomName4, roomDescr4);

              (21 rooms like this...)
```

AND:

ExitInit.h:

```
#ifndef EXITSINIT_H_INCLUDED
#define EXITSINIT_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class Room;

using namespace std;






#endif // EXITSINIT_H_INCLUDED
```

and ExitInit.cpp:

```
#include "exitsInit.h"
#include "exit.h"
#include "room.h"
#include "RoomsInit.h"




    vector<Exit*> exitVec;

    Exit* p_north1 = new Exit("north", p_on_the_beach_north, true, false);
    Exit* p_south1 = new Exit("south", p_on_the_beach_south1, true, false);
    Exit* p_east1 = new Exit("east", p_in_the_ocean, true, false);
    Exit* p_west1 = new Exit("west", p_in_the_jungle, true, false);
    exitVec.push_back(p_north1);
    exitVec.push_back(p_south1);
    exitVec.push_back(p_east1);
    exitVec.push_back(p_west1);

    (*p_deserted_beach).SetExitVec(exitVec);
    exitVec.clear();



    Exit* p_north2 = new Exit("north", p_caught_in_a_Current, true, false);
    Exit* p_south2 = new Exit("south", p_caught_in_a_Current, true, false);
    Exit* p_east2 =  new Exit("east", p_caught_in_a_Current, true, false);
    Exit* p_west2 = new Exit("west", p_deserted_beach, true, false);
    Exit* p_northeast2 = new Exit("northeast", p_caught_in_a_Current, true, false);
    Exit* p_northwest2 = new Exit("northwest", p_caught_in_a_Current, true, false);
    Exit* p_southeast2 = new Exit("southeast", p_caught_in_a_Current, true, false);
    Exit* p_southwest2 = new Exit("southwest", p_caught_in_a_Current, true, false);
    exitVec.push_back(p_north2);
    exitVec.push_back(p_south2);
    exitVec.push_back(p_east2);
    exitVec.push_back(p_west2);
    exitVec.push_back(p_northeast2);
    exitVec.push_back(p_northwest2);
    exitVec.push_back(p_southeast2);
    exitVec.push_back(p_southwest2);

    (*p_in_the_ocean).SetExitVec(exitVec);
    exitVec.clear();



    Exit* p_north3 = new Exit("north", p_caught_in_a_strong_current, true, false);
    Exit* p_south3 = new Exit("south", p_caught_in_a_strong_current, true, false);
    Exit* p_east3 = new Exit("east", p_caught_in_a_strong_current, true, false);
    Exit* p_west3 = new Exit("west", p_caught_in_a_strong_current, true, false);
    Exit* p_northeast3 = new Exit("northeast", p_caught_in_a_strong_current, true,                                      false);
    Exit* p_northwest3 = new Exit("northwest", p_caught_in_a_strong_current, true, false);
    Exit* p_southeast3 = new Exit("southeast", p_caught_in_a_strong_current, true, false);
    Exit* p_southwest3 = new Exit("southwest", p_caught_in_a_strong_current, true, false);
    exitVec.push_back(p_north3);
    exitVec.push_back(p_south3);
    exitVec.push_back(p_east3);
    exitVec.push_back(p_west3);
    exitVec.push_back(p_northeast3);
    exitVec.push_back(p_northwest3);
    exitVec.push_back(p_southeast3);
    exitVec.push_back(p_southwest3);

    (*p_caught_in_a_Current).SetExitVec(exitVec);
    exitVec.clear();


(etc...Exit objects for each room which also take room pointers as arguments to
 their constructors.  These Exit objects are passed to a vector which is, itself, 
 a data member of the Room class)
```

The problem I'm getting when compiling is lots of errors stating:

```
     P_on_the_beach_south was not declared in this scope....etc etc
```

It's my understanding that allocating objects on the Heap, as long as the allocation doesn't take place within a particular function - where the pointers to the objects could go out of scope once the function call is completed - would allow me 'global' access just like any typical global variable/constant.  All the files are included in main() and I THINK I have the necessary files included also within each of the different cpp files.  So, I don't exactly understand what I'm doing wrong.  I'd appreciate any help y'all could give.  I also can put up the various class files if that would help.  Thanks.

Comment: Never ever write `using namespace std;` in header files!

Comment: Do not. I repeat: Do not use raw pointers as owning pointers. / Check whether you need pointers at all, and iff, use shared_ptr or unique_ptr. / Do not use such a tumble of global vars. / You mention you're practicing: Which books do yoj use?

Comment: I started off using pointers to heap objects because I wanted rooms, items, creatures, etc to be accessible after the functions creating them had returned. The only examples I've really seen involve creating class objects within the main function, and I don't want my main() cluttered with hundreds of room/exit/item objects, so I wanted to stow those processes in separate cpp files. I'm figuring out how all these things kindof work together at this point. - Also I'm not incorporating anything  from C++11 type things until I get what I've studied, down. Will do so next year.

Comment: The first book i had was Accelerated C++, which was a little too accelerated for me at the time - no programming xp since learning BASIC in highschool back in the mid 80s.  I have a couple others (Learning C++ through Game Programming and C++ without Fear), but I've also run through a number of tutorials online as well as gleaned info from programming forums like this one.  I've got a 4 inch binder (now 6 inch) crammed full o' stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would write some code that takes a text-file that describes the rooms and such to form "list of rooms" and their exits in a vector. Either include this code and the source text file [perhaps with some encryption] in your distribution, or use this code to generate code that you then compile to make the actual game..

But to access your global varibles, you will need to declare them as `extern Room* p_deserted_beach;` in the place where they are used.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought about the text file angle at one point, but then decided against it. I was wondering what the 'typical' way is that people who write games include all of their rooms/items/players/ etc, and allow them to access each other, within their program.  I thought there might be some standard way of doing it that most everybody uses.  It may just be that Heap object pointers are usually declared in one place and then 'externed' everywhere else. I just didn't know.

Comment: There are usually SOME global variable(s), but you shouldn't have a huge number of them - if you do, "you're doing it wrong". Having text files just makes it easier to add more rooms, etc, without much coding work. I never completed my several attempts on writing an adventure game (because I ran out of ideas, usually), but the principle of "text file that is parses" is a fairly common principle.

Comment: At first, I thought it might be too complex a solution to use separate text files, but after having mulled it over, it seems the right way to go.  And I'll learn more about file i/o in the process, which is not a bad thing.  Thanks, Mats.